# Come faccio a capire quando “torta” corrisponde a “cake" e quando a “pie”?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, translation, english-comparison, cooking

Capisco che la parola italiana "torta" è l'equivalente dell'inglese "cake" e  "pie".

Se un menù indica "torta di mele, come faccio a sapere se è come la prima o la seconda immagine?

[image: questo]

[image: questo]

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @DaG Since you seem interested in keeping the [tag:cooking] tag, would you please add some description thereof?

Comment: Right. I've just slightly modified someone else's proposal about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I must admit that, as an Italian, I am not sure about the difference between “cake” and “pie” (apart from specific cases). In fact, I find the two images quite similar and both look like particular kinds of *torte*, while there are other *torte* that are much more different than those two differ between them.

It so happens that different languages partition concepts in different ways.<sup>1</sup> I understand that for an English speaker “cakes” and “pies” are clearly different concepts, while they are all *torte* for an Italian, just like Italian *scimmia* means both “monkey” and “ape”. There are lots of examples the other way around too, of course. For instance, an English “cup” corresponds at least to the distinct Italian words and notions of *tazza*, *tazzina*, *coppa* and sometimes to *bicchiere* too; or take “helmet”, which [can correspond in Italian to *elmo*, *elmetto* or *casco*](http://blog.terminologiaetc.it/2018/07/24/falsi-amici-helmet-elmetto/), and so on. (And I don't even mention, say, the several Italian words for what abroad one would simply call *pasta*.)

To go back to *torte*, of course there are in Italian several names for specific torte: *crostata*, *pastiera*, *millefoglie*, *sbrisolona*...

<sup>1 Here we are skirting the [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity).</sup>

Comment: Come aggiunta culinaria, si può dire che in italiano non c’è una traduzione per “apple pie”, che conserva il suo nome. L’apple pie ha un ripieno disposto tra due strati di pasta. Non è uno strudel, in cui il ripieno è avvolto in un unico strato di pasta. La torta di mele è tipicamente quella della prima foto, che si prepara facendo un impasto a cui si aggiunge il lievito.

Comment: @DaG This has been a funny ongoing conversation with my me and my tutor. Whenever I make a pie, I have to awkwardly try to explain what it is, even knowing that it will translate as "cake" in the end. *Crostata* is very close, but from what I've read they tend to be open, whereas a lot of pies in America are closed (the open pies are called *tarts*, or sometimes *crisps*, which seems to be a more accurate translation of *crostata*).

Comment: +1 for *sbrisolona* (and the excellent answer, of course) :)

Comment: I'm going to comment in English from now on, as I'm much more comfortable with it. @DaG: I agree that the pictures aren't as distinct as I would have liked. I chose 'apple' as a flavour rather arbitrarily and I searched on "Italian apple pie" and "Italian apple cake" for examples. For me (and I believe most native speakers of English) the distinction is that "cake" is rather like sweetened bread, whereas "pie" is characterized by a layer of pastry with a sweet filling, optionally topped by another layer of pastry.

Comment: Here's a more typical piece of cake (for North America at least): https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2943/15382132126_59a12b88d1_b.jpg and this is a piece of very North American apple pie: https://www.stayathomemum.com.au/cache/555x700-0/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Apple-Pie.jpg

Comment: @WilsonF For a similar distinction, Americans consider *cookies* and *biscuits* two different things. For the life of me in all the five years I spent there I couldn't understand the difference (and I spent a significant portion of departmental teatimes discussing it) . Italian simply does not consider *cake* and *(sweet) pie* different things. They are just declinations among infinite other possible declinations of the concept of *torta*. There isn't a special name for them, nor a reason to invent one.

Comment: @DenisNardin (Sorry, I know this is off topic and should be in a separate chat.) The most defining characteristic of a cookie is that it is sweet. (Savory cookies exist, but they are rare, and you have to _specify_ they're savory, at which point, "savory cookie" becomes its own class, separate from just "cookie".) They are _usually_ also smallish (easily held in one hand), round (except some sold in packages) and crunchy (though many, including me, prefer them less crunchy, or even chewy). But without sweetness, almost no North American would consider something a "cookie". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Non sono un cuoco ma credo che, in linea di massima, con "cake" possiamo identificare quello che in italiano chiamiamo "torta" (es: millefoglie, mimosa, ecc), invece un "pie" assomiglia di più a quella che noi chiamiamo "crostata". Inoltre "pie" mi sembra più adatto a definire i tortini salati.

Fonte: provate a scrivere ["cake torta"](https://www.google.it/search?biw=1301&bih=661&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=DmYqW96xCaHpsAeejIvYDg&q=cake%20torta&oq=cake%20torta&gs_l=img.3..0j0i7i30k1l3j0i8i7i30k1j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l3.21308.22402.0.22680.7.7.0.0.0.0.135.794.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.7.790...0i67k1j0i7i5i30k1.0.VQfTUKvYdpg) e ["pie torta"](https://www.google.it/search?biw=1301&bih=661&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=JWYqW6TMIoebkwWPuYXIDg&q=pie%20torta&oq=pie%20torta&gs_l=img.3..0i30k1j0i5i30k1l3j0i8i30k1l3j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1.247676.249433.0.249626.9.9.0.0.0.0.439.1156.0j6j4-1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.7.1152...0j0i67k1j0i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i5i30i19k1j0i8i30i19k1.0.6ZBeP3JrIsg) su Google Immagini e date un'occhiata ai risultati ;)

---

I'm not a cook but speaking generally with "cake" we can identify what in Italian is called "torta". A "pie" instead is more similar to what we call "crostata". Also I think "pie" can describe better a *[don't know how to translate this thing](https://www.google.it/search?q=tortino%20salato&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtvp3bvOLbAhXQ2qQKHZ4wAeUQ_AUICigB&biw=1301&bih=661)*.

Source: try searching ["cake torta"](https://www.google.it/search?biw=1301&bih=661&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=DmYqW96xCaHpsAeejIvYDg&q=cake%20torta&oq=cake%20torta&gs_l=img.3..0j0i7i30k1l3j0i8i7i30k1j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l3.21308.22402.0.22680.7.7.0.0.0.0.135.794.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.7.790...0i67k1j0i7i5i30k1.0.VQfTUKvYdpg) and ["pie torta"](https://www.google.it/search?biw=1301&bih=661&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=JWYqW6TMIoebkwWPuYXIDg&q=pie%20torta&oq=pie%20torta&gs_l=img.3..0i30k1j0i5i30k1l3j0i8i30k1l3j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1.247676.249433.0.249626.9.9.0.0.0.0.439.1156.0j6j4-1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.img..2.7.1152...0j0i67k1j0i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i5i30i19k1j0i8i30i19k1.0.6ZBeP3JrIsg) on Google Images and check the results ;)

Comment: I see your point, but a crostata has almost always a decoration of shortcrust (most often a kind of lattice), which I'm not sure is always the case of a pie. And pies, as you mention, may be savoury as well as sweet, while a crostata is alway sweet, generally with jam or ricotta cheese.

Comment: And, sorry for the nitpicking: about «"pie" can describe better...», the question was about the meaning of torta in English, not of pie in Italian. :) In other words, your answer and the mention of the two image searches are interesting, but more useful to understand the difference between “cake” and “pie” (which are OT here and well known to the OP) than how to disambiguate _torta_.

Comment: The Ligurian “torta pasqualina” would definitely qualify as “pie” in English.

Comment: @egreg This got me thinking. Torta Pasqualina reminds me of Pizza Rustica (don't know if that's the correct term, but that's what my aunt called it), which made me realize that a pizza is a sort of *flat pie*. In that it has a "filling" on a bread crust. A calzone would be the analogous closed-shell-pie. This could also possibly explain why, in English, a whole pizza is referred to as a "pie", and might be one of the reasons for this subtle language-specific difference.

Comment: @Jack_Kirby I think the closest English translation of *tortino salato* would be a [savory pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie#Savory_pies). But I'd need someone to confirm that as I'm not first-hand familiar with that class of dishes.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain whether _tortino salato_ is a pie or not, but it certainly looks delicious. I'm visiting Italy in September (which is why I've been trying to learn at least some Italian) and I will make a point of trying one of these.

Comment: I'm now interested to know what _tortino_ means on its own (assuming it's ever used by itself).

Comment: @Wilsin F. Good point. I would refer to tortino mostly for a little pie with salty filling.  It is interesting that a simple question resulted in so much nuances :)

Comment: “Tortino salato” looks like [“quiche”](https://www.google.it/search?sca_esv=be3ff3acc12850a5&sca_upv=1&q=quiche&tbm=isch) to me.