# In italiano ci sono mai state parole analoghe alle inglesi "cake" e "pie"?

Tags: word-choice, translation, english-comparison

In inglese le torte (salate e dolci) si dividono in *cake* e *pie*. In italiano solitamente non si fa questa distinzione (*apple pie* è "torta di mele" ma *birthday cake* è "torta di compleanno").

Ci sono mai state parole (anche regionali) che permettono di fare questa distinzione anche in italiano?

Comment: [Domanda correlata](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9593).

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Il problema è che l'arte pasticciera italiana (e tralasciamo tra le infinite varianti regionali) non è davvero compatibile con quella inglese (o, ugh, americana) per cui una traduzione corrispondente dei termini non funziona davvero. Per esempio, molti dolci italiani sono fatti con la pasta frolla, che semplicemente non esiste nel mondo anglosassone.

Comment: *Pie* non è usato solo per dolci; in italiano si può usare *tortino* ma anche *torta*, per esempio la *torta pasqualina* genovese.

Comment: Come avevamo già visto in occasione della tua altra domanda, questa è una distinzione che non esiste in italiano, e che per un italiano è difficile da capire quando studia l'inglese. Perché pensi che ci siano o siano state parole specifiche?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Come faccio a distinguere quand'è che “torta” corrisponde a “cake" e quando a “pie”?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9593/come-faccio-a-distinguere-quand%c3%a8-che-torta-corrisponde-a-cake-e-quando-a-p)

Comment: Mi sembrava strano perché non c'è solo in inglese la distinzione (p. es. anche in francese c'è tourte e gâteau) e quindi magari poteva esserci anche in italiano ma "torta" ha col tempo coperto entrambi i significati

Comment: Lorenzo, il fatto è che _cake_ e _pie_ non costituiscono una distinzione universale, non sono concetti assoluti. Neppure i colori o le specie animali sono concetti assoluti. Figuriamoci poi una cosa così strettamente legata alle usanze del posto.

Comment: @DaG È vero, ho capito